# Network drive seems empty over UNC-path (but actually isn't)

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, ftp, network-drive, unc

## Problem

Network drive seems to be empty when using UNC-notation. In windows explorer trying the following `\\192.168.1.1` shows my 2 drives (`G:`, `H:`) correctly, but if I want to access `G:` the windows explorer shows me "This folder is empty." while it works for `H:`. This message is new, as this has worked for months now. While I copied some big files to the network drive it suddenly stopped and wouldn't start again. (same in "Map network drive")

[image: UNC]

#### FTP

This works over FTP (also in "Add a network location")

[image: FTP]

#### Mapped

✅ Add a network location (left)

❌ Map network drive (right) -> although shows correct memory usage

[image: Windows explorer]

## Setup

- 2x WD MyBook external drive
- Notebook / PC / PC2 (all Windows 10)
- TP-Link Archer AX50 (AX3000)

[image: Router settings]

## Already Tried

- Tried different computers but all 3 do have the same problem. How can that be? (permissions?)
- Disabled offline files in Control panel > all control panel items > sync center (as I thought this could be a problem)
- Also via cmd
  [image]
- Thought it could be a windows problem, but it won't work from 3 different computers.

  - ❌ CMD (`Z:`)
  - ❌ Windows explorer (`\\192.168.1.1\g`)
  - ❌ (`file://192.168.1.1/g/`)

I'm feeling lost in the Windows online resource jungle. There's just so much stupid & useless information out there ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, Have You Tried Turning It Off and On Again?

Nevermind. I restarted the router and it works again ‍♂️ >.<